# Fetch Stored Procedure from Oracle Database Using C# Error

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0

I'm using C# to try and connect to a Stored Procedure in a suppliers Oracle database.  I have installed Oracle Net Manager and set up my connection and verified it in tnsnames.ora - testing the connection works ok.

I have some c# but when i run it i get the following error:

**System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 27:
PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'MAIN' reference is out of scope
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored**

Here's my c# code:

```
 public string StoredProc()
            {

                    string response = "default";

                    string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


                    try
                    {
                        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnn))
                        {
                            conn.Open();

                            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                            cmd.Connection = conn;

                            cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProc";

                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("applicationid", "App1"));


                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            dr.Read();

                            if (dr.Read())
                            {
                                response += dr["result"].ToString();
                            }

                            dr.Close();
                            cmd.Dispose();
                            conn.Close();
                        }


                        return response;

                    }
                    catch (Exception Error)
                    {
                        return response += Error.Message;
                    }
            }
```

I've never used Oracle before so any help is appreciated :)

thanks

Comment: It will be more helpful,if you put stored procedure sql code also here.

Comment: The stack trace means their is a sql error. I guess you should post the proc stock and the parameter your are sending.

Comment: Hi @HameedSyed i don't have access to it, it's a 3rd party supplier system and the Stored Procedure is encrypted

Comment: @Scott,at least make sure the sp is executed properly by passing the input.Mostly it looks like some parameter type issue.

Comment: @HameedSyed OK, i'll check with supplier if my params are correct.  thanks